# Spark streaming to Elasticsearch from Cassandra and MySQL correct configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I have inherited a cluster of mess and trying to figure out if this is the correct way to setup spark.

Goal: we have approx 13M records in Mysql across several tables that needs to be index in ElasticSearch. We have similarly have several million records in Cassandra that needs to be index in Elasticsearch also.

We do a total reindexation because a lot data gets changed in the DB and currently the application doesn't crud to ES.

All setup are on AWS Ec2 clusters with some RDS for MYSQL.

- I have 4 EC2 (m4.xlarge) machines running ElasticSearch Nodes.
- I have 3 EC2 machines running Cassandra Nodes
- I have 1 Master + 1 Slave RDS running MySQL.
- I have 1 C3.XLarge EC2 with Spark setup (everything is actually default configuration).

The scala application that was developed takes the mysql data, runs a mapping and transform them into RDD and push to the ES. Same goes for Cassandra.

Issue:
CPU + I/O taps out the ElasticSearch machines and I am at 100%. The entire process takes several hours.

Before I optimize code - should i be running the Spark system on standalone or should I be using it differently and why (so i can tell the IT I need to deploy or change the servers)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
{
  "timestamp": 1470397729366,
  "name": "es-server-1",
  "transport_address": "inet[/XXX.xx.xx.XX:9300]",
  "host": "es-server-1",
  "ip": [
    "inet[/xxx.xx.xx.XX:9300]",
    "NONE"
  ],
  "indices": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 13297950,
      "deleted": 4132597
    },
    "store": {
      "size": "19gb",
      "size_in_bytes": 20405153604,
      "throttle_time": "8.5h",
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 30887045
    },
    "indexing": {
      "index_total": 1306040463,
      "index_time": "39.4d",
      "index_time_in_millis": 3409319879,
      "index_current": 0,
      "delete_total": 3176,
      "delete_time": "468ms",
      "delete_time_in_millis": 468,
      "delete_current": 0,
      "noop_update_total": 0,
      "is_throttled": false,
      "throttle_time": "3.7h",
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 13387134
    },
    "get": {
      "total": 0,
      "get_time": "0s",
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "exists_total": 0,
      "exists_time": "0s",
      "exists_time_in_millis": 0,
      "missing_total": 0,
      "missing_time": "0s",
      "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "search": {
      "open_contexts": 2,
      "query_total": 91817250,
      "query_time": "7.7d",
      "query_time_in_millis": 669964087,
      "query_current": 0,
      "fetch_total": 6111935,
      "fetch_time": "26.8m",
      "fetch_time_in_millis": 1609543,
      "fetch_current": 0
    },
    "merges": {
      "current": 1,
      "current_docs": 140211,
      "current_size": "358.5mb",
      "current_size_in_bytes": 375921439,
      "total": 1308682,
      "total_time": "52.2d",
      "total_time_in_millis": 4515401497,
      "total_docs": 22683582490,
      "total_size": "18.3tb",
      "total_size_in_bytes": 20196592980131
    },
    "refresh": {
      "total": 6513707,
      "total_time": "5.9d",
      "total_time_in_millis": 515651065
    },
    "flush": {
      "total": 49408,
      "total_time": "1.7d",
      "total_time_in_millis": 147150501
    },
    "warmer": {
      "current": 0,
      "total": 1696226,
      "total_time": "26.4m",
      "total_time_in_millis": 1589979
    },
    "filter_cache": {
      "memory_size": "429.2mb",
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 450131652,
      "evictions": 1767369
    },
    "id_cache": {
      "memory_size": "0b",
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "fielddata": {
      "memory_size": "411mb",
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 431001032,
      "evictions": 0
    },
    "percolate": {
      "total": 0,
      "get_time": "0s",
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0,
      "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
      "memory_size": "-1b",
      "queries": 0
    },
    "completion": {
      "size": "0b",
      "size_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "segments": {
      "count": 272,
      "memory": "113.4mb",
      "memory_in_bytes": 118989720,
      "index_writer_memory": "0b",
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "index_writer_max_memory": "813.7mb",
      "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 853250866,
      "version_map_memory": "0b",
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "fixed_bit_set": "32.1mb",
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 33692696
    },
    "translog": {
      "operations": 0,
      "size": "17b",
      "size_in_bytes": 17
    },
    "suggest": {
      "total": 4,
      "time": "0s",
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "query_cache": {
      "memory_size": "0b",
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "evictions": 0,
      "hit_count": 0,
      "miss_count": 0
    }
  },
  "os": {
    "timestamp": 1470397728691,
    "uptime": "4.2h",
    "uptime_in_millis": 15430550,
    "load_average": [
      0.01,
      0.13,
      0.17
    ],
    "cpu": {
      "sys": 0,
      "user": 0,
      "idle": 98,
      "usage": 0,
      "stolen": 0
    },
    "mem": {
      "free": "1.5gb",
      "free_in_bytes": 1627320320,
      "used": "14.1gb",
      "used_in_bytes": 15200206848,
      "free_percent": 42,
      "used_percent": 57,
      "actual_free": "6.6gb",
      "actual_free_in_bytes": 7102046208,
      "actual_used": "9gb",
      "actual_used_in_bytes": 9725480960
    },
    "swap": {
      "used": "0b",
      "used_in_bytes": 0,
      "free": "0b",
      "free_in_bytes": 0
    }
  },
  "process": {
    "timestamp": 1470397729391,
    "open_file_descriptors": 1072,
    "cpu": {
      "percent": 8,
      "sys": "2.8d",
      "sys_in_millis": 247968490,
      "user": "55.5d",
      "user_in_millis": 4803132120,
      "total": "58.4d",
      "total_in_millis": 5051100610
    },
    "mem": {
      "resident": "8.8gb",
      "resident_in_bytes": 9499480064,
      "share": "490.4mb",
      "share_in_bytes": 514248704,
      "total_virtual": "13gb",
      "total_virtual_in_bytes": 14003888128
    }
  },
  "jvm": {
    "timestamp": 1470397728691,
    "uptime": "168.6d",
    "uptime_in_millis": 14575120452,
    "mem": {
      "heap_used": "4gb",
      "heap_used_in_bytes": 4337667264,
      "heap_used_percent": 51,
      "heap_committed": "7.8gb",
      "heap_committed_in_bytes": 8378908672,
      "heap_max": "7.8gb",
      "heap_max_in_bytes": 8378908672,
      "non_heap_used": "90.5mb",
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 94943920,
      "non_heap_committed": "112mb",
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 117506048,
      "pools": {
        "young": {
          "used": "263mb",
          "used_in_bytes": 275871008,
          "max": "266.2mb",
          "max_in_bytes": 279183360,
          "peak_used": "266.2mb",
          "peak_used_in_bytes": 279183360,
          "peak_max": "266.2mb",
          "peak_max_in_bytes": 279183360
        },
        "survivor": {
          "used": "513.3kb",
          "used_in_bytes": 525696,
          "max": "33.2mb",
          "max_in_bytes": 34865152,
          "peak_used": "33.2mb",
          "peak_used_in_bytes": 34865152,
          "peak_max": "33.2mb",
          "peak_max_in_bytes": 34865152
        },
        "old": {
          "used": "3.7gb",
          "used_in_bytes": 4061270560,
          "max": "7.5gb",
          "max_in_bytes": 8064860160,
          "peak_used": "5.8gb",
          "peak_used_in_bytes": 6271548128,
          "peak_max": "7.5gb",
          "peak_max_in_bytes": 8064860160
        }
      }
    },
    "threads": {
      "count": 75,
      "peak_count": 90
    },
    "gc": {
      "collectors": {
        "young": {
          "collection_count": 2827443,
          "collection_time": "22.1h",
          "collection_time_in_millis": 79772838
        },
        "old": {
          "collection_count": 2420,
          "collection_time": "4.2m",
          "collection_time_in_millis": 253792
        }
      }
    },
    "buffer_pools": {
      "direct": {
        "count": 3519,
        "used": "82.1mb",
        "used_in_bytes": 86127850,
        "total_capacity": "82.1mb",
        "total_capacity_in_bytes": 86127850
      },
      "mapped": {
        "count": 250,
        "used": "2.8gb",
        "used_in_bytes": 3045093527,
        "total_capacity": "2.8gb",
        "total_capacity_in_bytes": 3045093527
      }
    }
  },
  "thread_pool": {
    "generic": {
      "threads": 1,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 4,
      "completed": 16062931
    },
    "index": {
      "threads": 4,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 4,
      "completed": 35253
    },
    "bench": {
      "threads": 0,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 0,
      "completed": 0
    },
    "get": {
      "threads": 0,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 0,
      "completed": 0
    },
    "snapshot": {
      "threads": 0,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 0,
      "completed": 0
    },
    "merge": {
      "threads": 1,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 2,
      "completed": 3112788
    },
    "suggest": {
      "threads": 4,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 4,
      "completed": 4
    },
    "bulk": {
      "threads": 4,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 4,
      "completed": 46447866
    },
    "optimize": {
      "threads": 0,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 0,
      "completed": 0
    },
    "warmer": {
      "threads": 1,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 2,
      "completed": 159210301
    },
    "flush": {
      "threads": 1,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 2,
      "completed": 756948
    },
    "search": {
      "threads": 12,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 12,
      "completed": 133987209
    },
    "listener": {
      "threads": 2,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 2,
      "completed": 26868988
    },
    "percolate": {
      "threads": 0,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 0,
      "completed": 0
    },
    "management": {
      "threads": 5,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 1,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 5,
      "completed": 227031495
    },
    "refresh": {
      "threads": 1,
      "queue": 0,
      "active": 0,
      "rejected": 0,
      "largest": 2,
      "completed": 6532756
    }
  },
  "network": {
    "tcp": {
      "active_opens": 1782589,
      "passive_opens": 20362132,
      "curr_estab": 226,
      "in_segs": 2535219205,
      "out_segs": 2254643744,
      "retrans_segs": 227538,
      "estab_resets": 273558,
      "attempt_fails": 14303,
      "in_errs": 100,
      "out_rsts": 260243
    }
  },
  "fs": {
    "timestamp": 1470397728691,
    "total": {
      "total": "196.6gb",
      "total_in_bytes": 211110395904,
      "free": "177.4gb",
      "free_in_bytes": 190571290624,
      "available": "167.4gb",
      "available_in_bytes": 179800317952,
      "disk_reads": 567609070,
      "disk_writes": 216561071,
      "disk_io_op": 784170141,
      "disk_read_size": "15.6tb",
      "disk_read_size_in_bytes": 17215484946432,
      "disk_write_size": "23.2tb",
      "disk_write_size_in_bytes": 25537856344064,
      "disk_io_size": "38.8tb",
      "disk_io_size_in_bytes": 42753341290496,
      "disk_queue": "0",
      "disk_service_time": "0"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "path": "/data/elasticsearch/data0/es-server-1/nodes/0",
        "mount": "/data/elasticsearch/data0",
        "dev": "/dev/xvdf",
        "total": "98.3gb",
        "total_in_bytes": 105555197952,
        "free": "88.8gb",
        "free_in_bytes": 95364030464,
        "available": "83.7gb",
        "available_in_bytes": 89978544128,
        "disk_reads": 280044788,
        "disk_writes": 107670720,
        "disk_io_op": 387715508,
        "disk_read_size": "7.7tb",
        "disk_read_size_in_bytes": 8567588643840,
        "disk_write_size": "11.5tb",
        "disk_write_size_in_bytes": 12689373003776,
        "disk_io_size": "19.3tb",
        "disk_io_size_in_bytes": 21256961647616,
        "disk_queue": "0",
        "disk_service_time": "0"
      },
      {
        "path": "/data/elasticsearch/data1/es-server-1/nodes/0",
        "mount": "/data/elasticsearch/data1",
        "dev": "/dev/xvdg",
        "total": "98.3gb",
        "total_in_bytes": 105555197952,
        "free": "88.6gb",
        "free_in_bytes": 95207260160,
        "available": "83.6gb",
        "available_in_bytes": 89821773824,
        "disk_reads": 287564282,
        "disk_writes": 108890351,
        "disk_io_op": 396454633,
        "disk_read_size": "7.8tb",
        "disk_read_size_in_bytes": 8647896302592,
        "disk_write_size": "11.6tb",
        "disk_write_size_in_bytes": 12848483340288,
        "disk_io_size": "19.5tb",
        "disk_io_size_in_bytes": 21496379642880,
        "disk_queue": "0",
        "disk_service_time": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transport": {
    "server_open": 104,
    "rx_count": 883258049,
    "rx_size": "1.8tb",
    "rx_size_in_bytes": 2051353458225,
    "tx_count": 682553258,
    "tx_size": "1.6tb",
    "tx_size_in_bytes": 1804963466280
  },
  "http": {
    "current_open": 12,
    "total_opened": 19973834
  },
  "breakers": {
    "request": {
      "limit_size_in_bytes": 3351563468,
      "limit_size": "3.1gb",
      "estimated_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "estimated_size": "0b",
      "overhead": 1,
      "tripped": 0
    },
    "fielddata": {
      "limit_size_in_bytes": 5027345203,
      "limit_size": "4.6gb",
      "estimated_size_in_bytes": 431001032,
      "estimated_size": "411mb",
      "overhead": 1.03,
      "tripped": 0
    },
    "parent": {
      "limit_size_in_bytes": 5865236070,
      "limit_size": "5.4gb",
      "estimated_size_in_bytes": 431001032,
      "estimated_size": "411mb",
      "overhead": 1,
      "tripped": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the spec of your ES nodes? Can you update your question with the result you get from running this on one of your ES nodes: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats'`

Comment: @Val I have added the AWS instance. What information are you looking for in stats, its pretty extensive - so let me know which field from the stats you wish to know. Ill include the JVM first and let me know if you need more

Comment: Please share the full thing.

Comment: @Val updated with full node stats of one node.

Comment: Why would you want to change the spark setup if the problem seems to be with the ES machines? As for reindexing, are you using the [`ES bulk api`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html)? If anything the cluster seems somewhat oversized - 13M records is not a lot for either MySQL, Cassandra, nor ES (that's in light of the job you describe, ultimately depends on other factors i.e. the load on these components during normal operation).

Comment: @miraculixx because if this is an inefficient configuration of spark then it might resolve the issue. If this is an inefficient configuration of spark but i change ES instead, then its moot. Adding more ram thinking that ram is a bottleneck but yet splitting spark into smaller cluster with smaller ram can be more efficient...if someone can show me why it would be (just assuming)

Comment: well, the 1 spark machine already manages to overload a 4-node ES cluster, adding more spark nodes would likely increase the load excerted on the ES cluster due to more parallel processes running in spark. Then again that's just assuming because it really depends on how the spark job (scala code) is set up. Still, my hunch is that it's not the spark configuration as such that is the problem, rather the load generated by your scala program is. Suggest to take a small sample say 10% of the total data and try with that to find the actual bottleneck.